# Network adapters disabled on Lenovo laptop with Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop

My computer says that the network adapters are disabled, so I can't get onto the Internet.  I can't seem to enable them in the Control Panel.  When I go to Network Connections, there's nothing there, just a blank screen.

I went to Recovery and System Restore, and it said there were no restore points.

Specs:

- Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
- Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you sure network driver is installed, in control panel go to network and sharing center then in right panel go to change adapter setting. in this place you can enable or disable all your network adapter. sometimes virtualbox or vmware can disable your network adapter.